# Date Range Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following data

### Sr. FromDate    ToDate      Code

```
1   1990-01-01  2000-08-31  A        
2   2000-09-01  2001-05-31  B        
3   2001-06-01  2018-12-31  C
```

and need to write SQL query to find rows having code for 
date range= fromdate 1992-01-01 and ToDate 2000-12-31.

```
Select * 
From Table 
Where fromDate <= 1992-01-01 
and EndDate >=2000-12-31
```

not returning proper data.

Any help??

Expected output are first two rows which cover part of date mentioned in query.

---

One of possible query is:

Select * From table where fromdate <= 19920101 
UNION 
Select * From table where todate >= 20011231

But some how I don't like it and wanted easier alternative.

Comment: Have you tried "between '1992-01-01' and '2000-12-31'"?

Comment: It is returning proper data - you don't have any rows with fromdate less than 1992-01-01 and end date greater than 2000-12-31. Are you sure you didn't mean to say fromdate GREATER than 1992-01-01 and end date LESS than 2000-12-31 ?

Comment: Expected output first two rows. First row has from date less than 1992-01-01 and second row has end date greater than 2000-12-31.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the operators

```
select * 
from Table 
where fromDate >= '1992-01-01'
and EndDate <= '2000-12-31'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate the dat to a date object:

```
Select *
from table
where fromDate >= to_date('1992-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
and ...
```

Look here for valid date formats and syntax:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try reverse filtering, I mean change the dates in filtering:

```
WITH tab(ID, start_date, end_date, code) AS (
    SELECT 1, to_date('1990-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2000-08-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'A' FROM dual UNION ALL        
    SELECT 2, to_date('2000-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2001-05-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'B' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, to_date('2001-06-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'C' FROM dual)
-----------------
--End of data preparation
-----------------
SELECT * 
  FROM tab
 WHERE end_date >= to_date('1992-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
   AND start_date <= to_date('2000-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Output

```
| ID |                       START_DATE |                      END_DATE | CODE |
|----|----------------------------------|-------------------------------|------|
|  1 |   January, 01 1990 00:00:00+0000 | August, 31 2000 00:00:00+0000 |    A |
|  2 | September, 01 2000 00:00:00+0000 |    May, 31 2001 00:00:00+0000 |    B |
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said you have to put an OR. Is it really what you need?

```
Select *
From Table 
Where fromDate <= '1992-01-01'
OR EndDate >='2000-12-31'
```

Comment: Both condition needs to meet but many not be by same row i.e. we are trying to search row(s) which are having fromDate before or equal to '1992-01-01' and same or other row having  ToDate greater than or equal to '2000-12-31'

Comment: As StevieG said you have no record that satisfies both conditions. The OR operator will work as the UNION you didn't like.